# How to list the manual sections

Tags: macos, terminal

On my OS X Yosemite, when running `man man` I was excepting to see a list of `MANUAL SECTIONS` and their number, but I don't. As a Windows user until lately, I'm not familiar with the meaning of the different section numbers that are printed in parenthesis next to the command name.

So how do I list them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such information on OS X is instead located in `man manpages`, which is also available online [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/manpages.5.html):

> **MANUAL PAGE SECTIONS**
>
> The manual is divided into sections. Each section covers a particular subject area. The major manual page sections are:
>
> 1      General User Commands
>
> 2      System Calls
>
> 3      Library Routines (*)
>
> 4      Special Files and Sockets
>
> 5      File formats and Conventions
>
> 6      Games and Fun Stuff
>
> 7      Miscellaneous Documentation
>
> 8      System Administration
>
> 9      Kernel and Programming Style
>
> n      Tcl/Tk

Run `man manpages` in Terminal or open that link to read more in-depth information.